# JavaFx: How to install a Tooltip on ImageView

Tags: java, imageview, javafx, tooltip

I tried this:

```
public void addTargetCard(MissionCard mCard) {
    int card = mCard.GetID();
    leftSide.getChildren().removeAll(targetCardBox);
    Image image = new Image(
            MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream("images/target" + card
                    + ".png"));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(image);
    imageView.setFitHeight(81);
    imageView.setFitWidth(108);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);
    Tooltip.install(imageView, new Tooltip(intToCity(mCard.getStart())
            + " - " + intToCity(mCard.getFinish())));
    targetCardBox.getChildren().add(imageView);
    leftSide.getChildren().add(targetCardBox);
}
```

Can somebody explain me why my Tooltip doesn't work - i got no idea what i did wrong. (It's my first time that i use Tooltips's)

---

somebody else told me that ImageView doesnt work with tooltips and gave me this workaround - but i have again no tooltip when i move with my mouse over the label

```
    public void addTargetCard(MissionCard mCard) {
    int card = mCard.GetID();
    leftSide.getChildren().removeAll(targetCardBox);
    Image image = new Image(
            MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream("images/target" + card
                    + ".png"));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(image);
    imageView.setFitHeight(81);
    imageView.setFitWidth(108);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    label.setGraphic(imageView);
    label.setTooltip(new Tooltip(intToCity(mCard.getStart()) + " - "
            + intToCity(mCard.getFinish())));
    targetCardBox.getChildren().add(label);
    leftSide.getChildren().add(targetCardBox);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple example of tooltip on label and on imageview? Please show some effort. Have you any css styles that maybe causing the tooltip not to appear?

Comment: i tried a simple example i just dont had the right idea why i have no tooltip in that example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing a tooltip to image view is working. Try yourself with new sample JavaFX project and see it. When you doubt about some functionality of the used API (JavaFX in this case) try to isolate the doubted use case into new fresh environment/project and observe it closely.

P.S. Why are you removing the targetCardBox from leftSide and adding it again afterwards.

Comment: hmm k, I remove targetCardBox add it again because there is an update function that updates the content all the time

Comment: your p.s. was the best hint^^ - because i always update the targetcards there wasn't enough time to show a tooltip between two updates - thank you for your help^^

Comment: I don't think this is correct. ImageView is not a Control which has the tooltip property, it is a Node.

Comment: Tooltip.install(imageView, string) does work on ImageView Nodes.